# Detect VPN Connection

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-native, expo

Is there any way of detecting VPN connection on app launch in both Android and iOS React Native Expo app?

I already tried both Expo Network and NetInfo but none of them work for me.

Currently I am on expo version 47.0.0.